# Parse JSON message from socket using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm just looking for a really good hint on solving my problem, not necessarily the complete solution.

I can receive the following string over a TCP socket:

```
{"id":"555","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"timestamp":"2018-08-03T17:32:41.894"}
```

## this is how I'm reading in the data

```
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    if not data:
        sys.exit(0)
```

I'm trying to parse elements using the following method:

```
if (data["id"] == "555"):
    print("found it..now call a function!")
```

No matter what I try I get the following TypeError:
string indices must be integers

I'm using Python version 3.7. I'm new to Python and programming for that matter and I've been at this for days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't seem to be parsing it at all. You need to use `json.loads()` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in `json` library specifically for this kind of thing.

```
import json
...
data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')    # this returns a JSON-formatted String
parsed_data = json.loads(data)            # this turns the string into a python dict
if parsed_data['id'] == '555':            # because it is now a dictionary, this will work
    ...
```

Comment: I tried making the change you've suggested. However, I now have the following error:  File "C:\Users\LabUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)....thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that `data` actually is a string, and isn't empty or `None`?

Comment: print(type(data)) returns <class 'str'>. If I simply do print(data) I can see the complete string. If I create a very simple script with the string, your suggestion works perfectly. Could it be something related to receiving the jsonrpc 2.0 string from a socket connection? Could it be the <STX><ETX> padding required by jsonrpc? Over the weekend I thought maybe that was this issue and tried various methods to remove the special characters but I'd still get the TypeError: "string indices must be integers". Thank you....

Comment: addition info...print(data[0]) returns:
☻
{
♥
However, print(data[1]) returns IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: more info....when I modified my simple test script that works from print(data) to print(type(data)), I can see the data type is <class 'dict'> not <class 'str'>. So apparently I need to convert my string into a 'dict'? Thanks in advance....